# What does "along the handle of the cart" mean? And how does one calculate weight?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> A horizontal force is used to pull a $5.0\text{ kg}$ cart at a constant speed of $5.0\text{ m/s}$ across the floor. The force of friction between the cart and the floor is $10\text{ N}$.
>
> 1. What is the magnitude of the horizontal force along the handle of the cart?
> 2. Calculate the weight of the cart?
> 3. Calculate the coefficient of kinetic friction between the cart and the floor.

I'm not sure what they mean by "along the handle of the cart". Is that still the same as $F_{net}$? Also, I have no idea how I would calculate the weight.Is the weight just the normal Force? Because in order to do anything with $F_N$, I need $F_f$ and $\mu$ which I do not have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A horizontal force is used to pull a 5.0 kg cart at a constant speed of 5.0 m/s accross the floor. The force of friction between the cart and the floor is 10N.
>
> What is the magnitude of the horizontal force along the handle of the cart? Calculate the weight of the cart? Calculate the coefficient of kinetic friction between the cart and the floor.
>
> I'm not sure what they mean by "along the handle of the cart".

I presume this is the force in the horizontal direction.

> Is that still the same as $F_{net}$?

It is the horizontal component of ${\vec F}_{net}$

> Also, I have no idea how I would calculate the weight...is the weight just normal Force?

The weight of an object of mass $m$ is simply equal to $m g$ where $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity.

> Because in order to do anything with $F_N$, I need $F_f$ and $\mu$ which i do not have. So, i have no idea what to do.

$F_f$ is given to you. You can find $F_N$ by balancing forces along the vertical direction. This should allow you to compute $\mu$.

Comment: Note $\vec{F}_{\textrm{net}}$ is zero in this case.

Comment: Agree. But I thought he/she should figure that out for him/herself.

Comment: @Prahar Also, the force along the handle of the cart is not F_net.  F_net is the vector addition of "the force along the handle of the cart" and the force of friction.  So while the net force is 0, the force along the handle of the cart is 10.

Comment: @Chris - What do you mean? Surely, since $F_f = \mu F_N$ he needs to evaluate the normal force. Of course in this case, $F_N$ is equal to the weight, so you could just work with the weight, but you are skipping a step there.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1.**
Because the cart is travelling at a constant velocity, the net force on the cart must be 0.  This means the force at which the cart is pulled must balance the force of friction.
Therefore, the magnitude of the horizontal force along the handle is also 10N.

**Question 2**
Weight = mg = 5*10 = 50 N (assuming g = 10)

**Question 3**
Force of friction = Normal Force * Coefficient

The Normal Force in this case is simply the weight, so,

Force of friction = Weight*Coefficient

Substituting in numbers gives,

10 = 50*Coefficient

Therefore,

Coefficient = 0.2